# Live strings on Epiphone sg special 2

Tags: guitar

Iv'e just purchased a Epiphone sg special 2 and a fender mustang 1 v2 amp.
The problem I've got is when I connected it all up I fretted a string it played a note as if the strings were live. When I let the string go it sounded again. Is it the guitar or amp or just amp settings.

Comment: This seems perfectly normal - when you fret a string you should be able to hear it play. Can you give more details.

Comment: sounds like what happens when the gain is up high, which would be an amp setting.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm a complete novice only second time holding an electric guitar.I set all the amp dials at one then turned up the master till I got a response I then fretted a string and it sounded just like plucking a note.I then thought the previous owner might have dialled in an affect but I can't tell. A little knowledge is dangerous so what is none.

Comment: this is a feature of guitars to some extent. Some few guitarists leverage this to an extreme, such as Stanley Jordan. The following is a link to Stanley Jordan playing in a Trio Live in Paris. It may look like a piano thing, until about 2:20 mins (Feelings of Inadequacy Warning(tm): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9Ae3R6QP6c

Answer (score 1):

With an electric guiatr hooked up to an amp with medium to high gain, fretting a string (otherwise known as hammering-on) will make the note sound, almost exactly as if you had picked or plucked that string.

The same happens when you remove your finger (pulling off)

This is generally considered a very good thing in playing electric guitar, as it allows smooth legato runs, faster notes and runs and even allows you to play a melody line using hammer ons and pull offs while picking a bass line, for example.

If you don't like it, you need to back off the gain, and perhaps learn to damp the unneeded strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you press a string down *gently*, more than likely, unless the amp and guitar are extremely loud, it won't happen. Likewise, taking that finger off, gently, will stop the sound of the open string. Unless the fingers are sticky!

It's hammer-on for the first effect, and if you do want the string to sound again as you pull your fretting finger slightly to one side, it's pull-off. Both very good techniques that guitarists use all of the time.

Comment: Thanks again for the info. I reset the amp to factory settings and it seems to have done the trick.